# How make Seam3 Solder with CDI work in WebSphere 7?

Tags: jsf-2, cdi, jboss-weld, websphere-7, seam3

I want to use Seam Solder and Seam Faces 3 in WebSphere 7 with JSF 2.0 (RI is Mojarra 2.0.4) and CDI. I Included all required dependencies (Weld 1.1, JBoss Logging), but the server doesn't start saying:

> Failed to locate BeanManager using any of these providers:
>   org.jboss.seam.solder.beanManager.DefaultJndiBeanManagerProvider(11),
>   org.jboss.seam.solder.beanManager.ServletContainerJndiBeanManagerProvider(10)`

I followed the [Seam configuration instruction for pre-servlet 3.0 environment](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/3/faces/latest/reference/en-US/html_single/#pre-servlet-3)

It seemed to me a resource (the BeanMananger) is missing and I tried to set up the BeanManager as a jndi resource in Websphere, following this [Weld instruction](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/1.1.0.Final/en-US/html/environments.html#d0e5221) for Servlet Container, which also did not work.

The source code causing the exception during server startup, tries to lookup the bean manager like this:

```
class ServletContainerJndiBeanManagerProvider extends AbstractJndiBeanManagerProvider {  
@Override  
protected String getLocation() {  
    return "java:comp/env/BeanManager";  
}  
public int getPrecedence(){  
    return 10;  
}
```

Did anyone get Seam 3 and CDI 1.0 (resp. Weld 1.1) running on Websphere 7 so far? What am I missing here?

P.S.: JSF 2.0 is running fine.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a link to a thread on the seam-dev mailist about trying to get Seam 3 to work in Websphere 8.  Maybe some tidbits in there will be helpful for you.

http://seam-framework.2283336.n4.nabble.com/seam-booking-from-CR3-preliminary-testing-results-on-WebSphere-v8-beta-td3395111.html